# Improve the quality of the code with dry concept

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a code like below. Bydefault location is myloc. When user click btn-a it selects myloc and when btn-b is clicked it select myloc1. In my code I have repeat the code L.circle.... three times which is bad practice. So Can anybody help me how can I optimize this code and improve the quality as well.

```
var myloc = new L.LatLng(13.7433242, 100.5421583);
var myloc1 = new L.LatLng(14.979900, 102.097771);
$(function () {
    var circle;
    var slider = document.getElementById('myRange');
    var output = document.getElementById('demo');
    output.innerHTML = slider.value + scale;

    slider.oninput = function (val) {
        output.innerHTML = this.value + scale;
        circle.setRadius(this.value);
    }

    circle = L.circle(myloc, {
        color: '#7a7777',
        weight: 0.1,
        fillColor: '#7a7777',
        fillOpacity: 0.2,
        radius: 0
    }).addTo(map);

    $('.btn-a').on('click', function(e){
        if ($(this).val() == 'First') {
            circle = L.circle(myloc, {
                color: '#7a7777',
                weight: 0.1,
                fillColor: '#7a7777',
                fillOpacity: 0.2,
                radius: 0
            }).addTo(map);

        } else if($(this).val() == 'Second') {
            circle = L.circle(myloc1, {
                color: '#7a7777',
                weight: 0.1,
                fillColor: '#7a7777',
                fillOpacity: 0.2,
                radius: 0
            }).addTo(map);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: You want to know how to define a function?

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen I want to know how can I reduce the line of code and improve code quality as well. I am working on my thesis

Comment: A simple helper function that returns `L.circle` would streamline that part. Just call the function and pass in the `loc` and whatever other params would be different

Comment: *«how can I optimize this code»* == Post it on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the only difference is that the third `L.circle` is passed a parameter of `myloc1` instead of `myloc`. One option would be to have a function that returns a `L.circle` with the first parameter.

```
// ...
slider.oninput = function(val) {
  output.innerHTML = this.value + scale;
  circle.setRadius(this.value);
}

const circleProps = {
  color: '#7a7777',
  weight: 0.1,
  fillColor: '#7a7777',
  fillOpacity: 0.2,
  radius: 0
};
const newCircle = (loc) => {
  circle = L.circle(loc, {...circleProps}).addTo(map);
}
newCircle(myloc);
$('.btn-a').on('click', function(e) {
  if ($(this).val() == 'First') newCircle(myloc);
  else if ($(this).val() == 'Second') newCircle(myloc2);
});
```

Comment: your code did worked but when I try using your code I am not sure why there is a small circle already around my marker